# Linking properly object files with nvcc (CUDA-RINSIDE)

Tags: c++, r, cuda

I'm trying to make `Rinside` work with some **CUDA code**. The first time I tried to compile them directly with **NVCC** but it was impossible to handle Rinside with nvcc, so now I'm trying another way.

I compile Rinside code with `g++` and obtain the object files `(.o)` then compile some CUDA code with nvcc and obtain the other `.o`, then link them together but I get some "unreference error".

This is the RINSIDE CODE:

```
#include <RInside.h>                            // for the embedded R via RInside

extern "C"
void someCUDAcode();


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    RInside R(argc, argv);                      // create an embedded R instance 
    someCUDAcode();
    exit(0);

}
```

And this is the CUDA CODE:

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <R.h>

__global__ void mykernel(int a){
  int id = threadIdx.x;
  int b = a;
  b++;
  id++;
}


extern "C"
void someCUDAcode() {
  mykernel<<<1, 1>>>(1);
}
```

And this is my makefile:

```
## and set R_HOME accordingly as an environment variable
R_HOME :=       $(shell R RHOME)

sources :=      $(wildcard *.cpp)
programs :=         $(sources:.cpp=)


## include headers and libraries for R 
RCPPFLAGS :=        $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config --cppflags)
RLDFLAGS :=         $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config --ldflags)
RBLAS :=        $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config BLAS_LIBS)
RLAPACK :=      $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config LAPACK_LIBS)

## if you need to set an rpath to R itself, also uncomment
#RRPATH :=      -Wl,-rpath,$(R_HOME)/lib

## include headers and libraries for Rcpp interface classes
## note that RCPPLIBS will be empty with Rcpp (>= 0.11.0) and can be omitted
RCPPINCL :=         $(shell echo 'Rcpp:::CxxFlags()' | $(R_HOME)/bin/R --vanilla --slave)
##RCPPLIBS :=       $(shell echo 'Rcpp:::LdFlags()'  | $(R_HOME)/bin/R --vanilla --slave)


## include headers and libraries for RInside embedding classes
RINSIDEINCL :=      $(shell echo 'RInside:::CxxFlags()' | $(R_HOME)/bin/R --vanilla --slave)
RINSIDELIBS :=      $(shell echo 'RInside:::LdFlags()'  | $(R_HOME)/bin/R --vanilla --slave)

## compiler etc settings used in default make rules
ifeq ($(HOST_OS),darwin)
    CXX := clang++ $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config CXX)
else
    CXX := $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config CXX)
endif
CPPFLAGS :=         -Wall $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config CPPFLAGS)
CXXFLAGS :=         $(RCPPFLAGS) $(RCPPINCL) $(RINSIDEINCL) $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config CXXFLAGS)
LDLIBS :=       $(RLDFLAGS) $(RRPATH) $(RBLAS) $(RLAPACK) $(RCPPLIBS) $(RINSIDELIBS)

#########################################
CUDA_HOME = /usr/local/cuda-9.1


# This defines what the shared object libraries will be
PKG_LIBS= -L/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/cuda-9.1/lib64 -lcudart -d

NVCC = $(CUDA_HOME)/bin/nvcc
CUDA_INC = $(CUDA_HOME)/include 
CUDA_LIB = $(CUDA_HOME)/lib64
R_INC = /usr/share/R/include
LIBS = -lcudart -d
NVCC_FLAGS = -Xcompiler "-fPIC" -I$(R_INC)

##-gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 
### Define objects
cu_sources := $(wildcard *cu)
cu_sharedlibs := $(patsubst %.cu, %.o,$(cu_sources))

cpp_sources := $(wildcard *.cpp)
cpp_sharedlibs := $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(cpp_sources))

OBJECTS = $(cu_sharedlibs) $(cpp_sharedlibs)

all : test.exe

test.exe: $(OBJECTS)

%.o: %.cpp $(cpp_sources)
        $(CXX) $< -c -fPIC -I$(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

%.o: %.cu $(cu_sources)
        $(NVCC) $(NVCC_FLAGS) -I$(CUDA_INC) $< -c
```

When I do "make" the makefile compile properly everything, I obtain my `.o` files but, then can't create the executable. When I try to compile them with "`nvcc` `test.o` `cuda.o`" I get this error:

```
pesco@pesco-PC:~/Scrivania/PURECUDA$ nvcc -o someCUDAcode.o test.o
test.o: nella funzione "Rcpp::Rstreambuf<false>::xsputn(char const*, long)":
/home/pesco/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/iostream/Rstreambuf.h:56: riferimento non definito a "REprintf"
test.o: nella funzione "Rcpp::Rstreambuf<false>::sync()":
/home/pesco/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/iostream/Rstreambuf.h:80: riferimento non definito a "R_FlushConsole"
test.o: nella funzione "Rcpp::Rstreambuf<true>::sync()":
/home/pesco/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/iostream/Rstreambuf.h:76: riferimento non definito a "R_FlushConsole"
test.o: nella funzione "Rcpp::Rstreambuf<true>::xsputn(char const*, long)":
/home/pesco/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/iostream/Rstreambuf.h:52: riferimento non definito a "Rprintf"
/home/pesco/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/iostream/Rstreambuf.h:52: riferimento non definito a "Rprintf"
test.o: nella funzione "Rcpp::Rstreambuf<false>::xsputn(char const*, long)":
/home/pesco/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/iostream/Rstreambuf.h:56: riferimento non definito a "REprintf"
test.o: nella funzione "main":
/home/pesco/Scrivania/PURECUDA/test.cpp:18: riferimento non definito a "RInside::RInside(int, char const* const*, bool, bool, bool)"
/home/pesco/Scrivania/PURECUDA/test.cpp:19: riferimento non definito a "someCUDAcode"
/home/pesco/Scrivania/PURECUDA/test.cpp:18: riferimento non definito a "RInside::~RInside()"
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

but I don't know how to handle this error. How can I link them together properly? Thank you :)

I'm working with:

CUDA 9.1:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Nov__3_21:07:56_CDT_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.1, V9.1.85
```

NVIDIA DRIVER:

```
pesco@pesco-PC:~/Scrivania/PURECUDA$ nvidia-smi
Mon Jul 23 11:16:50 2018       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.48                 Driver Version: 390.48                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GT 740M     Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
| N/A   58C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    110MiB /  2004MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

UBUNTU 16.04 LTS
G++: g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 5.4.0 20160609

I hope I was clear, sorry for my English!

Comment: I would suggest using the Rinside build system and then just link the additional CUDA object file and library (libcudart.so). There are a lot of R internals you would apparently need to link to make it work as you have shown in your question and I am not sure that is feasible

Comment: It seems that `R CMD config --ldflags` should tell you what things you need to link and the paths required to link them if you want nvcc to do this for you

Comment: Thank you very much!! I will try make that immediatly!

Comment: OMG It work!! starting from Rinside build system and then adding the .o and libcudart.so make it working, thank you so much !

Comment: Please write a short answer detaling how you solved the problem. I will upvote it to make sure this question is marked as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @talonmies suggested you can resolve the "unreference error" just adding the CUDA object file and library while compiling it with g++, to be exactly I taked a fresh makefile located in the example folder of RInside and then I added to LDLIBS the path of the .o and the .so I just obtained from the previous compilation I made and everything worked, I don't know If it work properly but, at least we have an executable! To be exactly this is the new makefile:

```
R_HOME :=       $(shell R RHOME)

sources :=      $(wildcard *.cpp)
programs :=         $(sources:.cpp=)


## include headers and libraries for R 
RCPPFLAGS :=        $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config --cppflags)
RLDFLAGS :=         $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config --ldflags)
RBLAS :=        $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config BLAS_LIBS)
RLAPACK :=      $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config LAPACK_LIBS)

## if you need to set an rpath to R itself, also uncomment
#RRPATH :=      -Wl,-rpath,$(R_HOME)/lib

## include headers and libraries for Rcpp interface classes
## note that RCPPLIBS will be empty with Rcpp (>= 0.11.0) and can be omitted
RCPPINCL :=         $(shell echo 'Rcpp:::CxxFlags()' | $(R_HOME)/bin/R --vanilla --slave)
RCPPLIBS :=         $(shell echo 'Rcpp:::LdFlags()'  | $(R_HOME)/bin/R --vanilla --slave)

##NVCC HEADER AND DECLARATION TO CREATE THE CUDA OBJECT FILE

## include headers and libraries for RInside embedding classes
RINSIDEINCL :=      $(shell echo 'RInside:::CxxFlags()' | $(R_HOME)/bin/R --vanilla --slave)
RINSIDELIBS :=      $(shell echo 'RInside:::LdFlags()'  | $(R_HOME)/bin/R --vanilla --slave)

## compiler etc settings used in default make rules
CXX :=          $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config CXX)
CPPFLAGS :=         -Wall $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config CPPFLAGS)
CXXFLAGS :=         $(RCPPFLAGS) $(RCPPINCL) $(RINSIDEINCL) $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config CXXFLAGS)
LDLIBS :=       $(RLDFLAGS) $(RRPATH) $(RBLAS) $(RLAPACK) $(RCPPLIBS) $(RINSIDELIBS) /home/pesco/Scrivania/NEWTRY/someCUDAcode.o /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so


all:        $(programs)
            @test -x /usr/bin/strip && strip $^

run:            $(programs)


clean:
            rm -vf $(programs)
            rm -vrf *.dSYM
```

And the new .cpp:

```
#include <RInside.h>         

extern "C"
void someCUDAcode();
           // for the embedded R via RInside

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    RInside R(argc, argv);              // create an embedded R instance 

    someCUDAcode();

    R["txt"] = "Hello, world!\n";   // assign a char* (string) to 'txt'

    R.parseEvalQ("cat(txt)");           // eval the init string, ignoring any returns

    exit(0);
}
```

this is what I obtain doing "make":

```
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -I/home/pesco/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rcpp/include -I/home/pesco/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/RInside/include -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -Wall    rinside_sample0.cpp  -Wl,--export-dynamic -fopenmp  -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR -lpcre -llzma -lbz2 -lz -lrt -ldl -lm  -lblas -llapack  -L/home/pesco/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/RInside/lib -lRInside -Wl,-rpath,/home/pesco/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/RInside/lib /home/pesco/Scrivania/NEWTRY/someCUDAcode.o /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so -o rinside_sample0
```

and running the executable:

```
pesco@pesco-PC:~/Scrivania/NEWTRY$ ./rinside_sample0 
Hello, world!
```

Comment: Perfect! In a few days you will be able to accept your answer if you so wish.

Comment: Thank you so much man, I will continue working on it and in case I found something strange I will immediatly report it ! For now looks fine, again, thank you !